# Marry tags iso27000 and iso27001 - and possible future tags iso27002-27k-n - to iso2700x tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Let's don't have a tag for every other ISO 27k standard. They are so much in the same ballpark topic-wise, that they deserve to be under the same tag.

EDIT:

I did a quick search on all questions regarding ISO 27002 to ISO 27005 so that everybody knows what we are dealing with here. It's not a lot numberwise, which I thinks speaks for my point, to form one tag for all ISO standards and not go through the trouble to maintain a tag for every single standard.

[Questions regarding ISO 27002, 37 results, tagged either iso27000, regulation, compliance, other or not tagged](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=iso%2027002)

[Questions regarding ISO 27003, 2 results, not tagged](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=iso%2027003)

[Questions regarding ISO 27004, 1 result, not tagged](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=iso%2027004)

[Questions regarding ISO 27005, 12 results, either tagged with iso27000 or not tagged at all](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=iso%2027005)

Comment: I disagree completely. They are related, yes, but there is a huge variety in there. tagging makes things very easy to find.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'll leave it to you then, in my opinion tagging them all as [tag:regulation] should be enough, but...

Comment: Well, I've only popped this in as a comment as it's a community decision to make. But using the specific one, and regulation as well probably will work.

Comment: "Regulation" smells like a meta-tag to me. Even the tag wiki is a copy-paste. No usage guidance, either.

Comment: I’m inclined to agree with Rory on this. ISO standards are distinct entities with distinct aims.  Using ‘regulation’ as a blanket term from all compliance also feels like a very general tag for such a diverse range of requirements.

Comment: I definitely agree on the 'regulation' point of TheJulyPlot and S.L.Barth. If we follow @RoryAlsop's point though, then there should be a tag for every major ISO standard and currently there are only two, one for ISO 27000 and one for ISO 27001. So if the community is not inclined to form one tag for all questions regarding relevant ISO standards then I would suggest to at least create tags for each one of them. IMO that would be ISO 27k to 27k5 and maybe ISO 31000.

Comment: Tags for other standards, like your ISO31000 example, would be created when someone asks a question regarding them.  Tags aren't created in advance.